# Create MSBuild task that recursively copies a folder to several projects in my solution

Tags: msbuild

I'm new to MSBuild and I tried reading up on several sources on the net but I'm missing somet things..

Here's what I want:

- A build task that on execution recursively copies a directory structure from a (hardcoded/configured) path on my machine to a set of projects in the solution
- Then compiles (release/debug, I guess I can make two sets of them)
- Preferably this process would be called when I press f5 in VS and is selectable from the release/debug dropdown (with a different name off course).

What I don't get yet:

- Where do I place my .proj file? In my root (where my sln file is)?
- How can I make VS pick it up (bind it to f5).

Comment: I just answered a question very similar to this, see my entry at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924972/msbuild-copy-to-several-locations-based-on-list-of-destination-parameter/934896#934896](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924972/msbuild-copy-to-several-locations-based-on-list-of-destination-parameter/934896#934896). Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi My Book: [Inside the Microsoft Build Engine : Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0735626286?ie=UTF8&tag=sedodream-20&linkCode=xm2&camp=1789&creativeASIN=0735626286)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [Copy Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx) examples on how to copy a file structure recursively.