# MSBuild Copy batching issue

Tags: msbuild, copy, batching

Say I have a project structure with 3 applications:

```
├───app1
├───app2
├───app3
```

I want to have an msbuild task to copy the relevant output of each application to a separate deployment location

```
deploy\app1\<app1.output>
deploy\app2\<app2.output>
deploy\app3\<app3.output>
```

The script below does the following instead:

```
deploy\app1\<app1.output> + <app2.output> + <app3.output>
deploy\app2\<app1.output> + <app2.output> + <app3.output>
deploy\app3\<app1.output> + <app2.output> + <app3.output>
```

I know there is something wrong with the batching, but I cannot figure out how to fix it.
Any ideas where I've got it wrong?

```
<Target Name="Deploy">
    <!-- Ensure the target home exists -->
    <MakeDir Directories="$(DeployPath)" />

    <!-- Select artefacts -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectPath Include="%(Project.BuildOutput)" />
        <ArtefactSource Include="%(ProjectPath.RootDir)%(ProjectPath.Directory)**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- copy files to respective artefact location -->
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(ArtefactSource)" DestinationFolder="$(DeployPath)\%(Project.Identity)"
         Condition="'%(Project.CanDeploy)' AND '%(Project.TestWasRun)' != 'Error'" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, based on the following SO post:
[How can I use MSBuild Copy Task to Copy To Multiple Destination Folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689651/how-can-i-use-msbuild-copy-task-to-copy-to-multiple-destination-folders)

My problem was not having an 'Outputs' attribute.  Target batching (what I needed) only works when this is in place.

So, I modified the target from:

```
<Target Name="Deploy">
```

to

```
<Target Name="Deploy" Outputs="%(Project.Identity)">
```

and all was good.